# Question on surjectivity, involving a function and its derivative

Tags: calculus, functions

Yesterday I came across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/819552/145141) question. It seems very hard to answer without finding an answer to the next question first:

> Is there a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that both $f$ and $f'$ are surjective?

For what I can tell,  we **don't** seem to be looking for a continously differentiable function. Can anyone prove/disprove/elaborate on this statement?

**N.B** I simply asked this question because it intrigues me. The link in the first line is merely the place where I "came up with" the idea...

Comment: Take $f(x)=x \sin x$.

Comment: As the user before me stated, the function $x\sin x$ is an example of what you are looking for, and there are many others. What you cannot find is a function that is bijective and has a bijective derivative, since negative derivatives mean a decreasing function while positive ones mean a increasing function, and bijections cannot be both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about $\cos(x)(e^x + e^{-x})$

Comment: $= 2\cos x\, \cosh x$.